# What is the distance between $HP$ and $AC$ in the cube $ABCDEFGH$ with side length $10$cm if $P$ is the intersection point of $AF$ and $BE$?

Tags: geometry

I don't know what plane passing through one of the given line to construct so it simplifies the determination of the distance

Comment: What is the issue in using coordinates? Also, please add a diagram. It is pretty difficult to understand where $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ really lie otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If we set $A=(0,0,0)$ and $B=(2,0,0)$ then $P=(1,0,1)$, $H=(0,2,2)$ and $C=(2,2,0)$.

So, for arbitrary point $X$ on $HD$ exist such $t$, that $$X = t(1,0,1)+(1-t)(0,2,2)=(t,2-2t,2-t)$$

and for arbitrary point $Y$ on $AC$ exist such $s$, that $$Y = s(2,2,0)+(1-s)(0,0,0)=(2s,2s,0)$$

Then $$XY = \sqrt{(t-2s)^2+(2-2t-2s)^2+(2-t)^2}$$

So we have to find a minimum of $$\begin{eqnarray}f(x,y) &=& 8s^2+4ts+6t^2-12t-8s+8\\
&=& 8s^2+4s(t-2)+6t^2-12t+8\\
&\geq & -{1\over 32}(16(t-2)^2-32(6t^2-12t+8))\\
&=& {1\over 2}(11t^2-20t+12)\\
&\geq & {1\over 2}{4\cdot 32\over 44}\\
& =&{16\over 11}
\end{eqnarray}$$

So actual distance is ${80\over 11}$cm